# Create an absolute or relative time period class in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I want to create some class that can calculate absolute or relative time period.
Meaning: the constructor will get either time period and units ( 3 weeks ) or two `DateTime` start and finish time. I have wrote the following code :

```
public class TimePeriod
{

    public State TimePerriodState { get; private set; }
    public RelativeTime RelativeTimePeriod { get; private set; }
    public int UnitsOfTime { get; private set; }

    public DateTime? StartTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; private set; }

    public TimePeriod(RelativeTime relativeTime, int unitsOfTime)
    {
        TimePerriodState = State.Absolute;
        RelativeTimePeriod = relativeTime;
        UnitsOfTime = unitsOfTime;
    }

    public TimePeriod(DateTime startTime , DateTime endTime)
    {
        TimePerriodState = State.Relative;
        StartTime = startTime;
        EndTime = endTime;
    }


    public enum State
    {
        None,
        Absolute,
        Relative
    }

    public enum RelativeTime
    {
        None,
        Hours,
        Days,
        Weeks,
        Months,
        Year
    }
}
```

But I don't like that the usage is base on the state. 
In the end the data will appear in the UI as two different controls. Is there a better way of making the API little better? Maybe pass in the data and calculate the dateTime on the fly or some thing like that?

**UPDATE :**

the usage is relative to any time its being used. meaning enter a timespan is not possible. lets say we need fo have the relative time prior 10 days from now or fixed days from X to Y

The `TimeSpan` will be calculated in a different BL class (this is a POCO class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically trying to store the same data twice.

You can define any period of time by either:

- A startdate and enddate, duration can be calculated by subtraction.
- A startdate and duration (TimeSpan), Enddate can be calculated by adding the two.
- You could do it with a duration and enddate but that's making things harder.

What you want to do is pick one way of storing it. If you want it the other way, write a function to calculate it. E.g:

```
public TimePeriod(DateTime startTime , DateTime endTime)
{
    StartTime = startTime;
    EndTime = endTime;
}

public TimePeriod(DateTime startTime , TimeSpan length)
{
    StartTime = startTime;
    EndTime = startTime + length;
}

public TimeSpan GetDuration()
{
    return EndTime - StartTime;
}

//Else you can just get the StartTime or EndTime variable (DateTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with your terminology / domain understanding. Time periods are always relative by definition. An absolute time period would be a fixed date!

Can you instead use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) struct which is part of the framework? You can then 'decorate' it in some way to indicate where this time-span was calculated from.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I doubt that using some sort of UnitsOfTime is a very good idea. Try use TimeSpan instead and UI will show weeks or months. Try something like this:

```
public class TimePeriod
{
    private readonly DateTime? _startDate;
    private readonly DateTime? _endDate;
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeSpan;

    public TimePeriod(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        if (_startDate > _endDate)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        _startDate = startDate;
        _endDate = endDate;
        _timeSpan = endDate - startDate;
    }

    public TimePeriod(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        _timeSpan = timeSpan;
    }

    public TimeSpan TimeSpan
    {
        get { return _timeSpan; }
    }

    public DateTime? StartDate
    {
        get { return _startDate; }
    }

    public DateTime? EndDate
    {
        get { return _endDate; }
    }

    public bool IsAbsolute
    {
        get { return _startDate.HasValue; }
    }
}
```

Also could you explain the reason why you need this class? It could help.